# Responsive Image Gallery without whitespace

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, image-gallery

Im trying to create a responsve image gallery, like a grid from a selection of images from a database. I have used bootstrap to create columns for list elements.

Because the images are different sizes/aspect ratios (maybe even portrait landscape) the images below dont fit and are moved along to a accomadating column, creating unwanted whitespace.

Can anyone suggest a method to resize/adjust the images without cropping or changing aspect ratio (preferably using pure css) to enable all grid spaces/columns to contain an image?

EXAMPLE:

[image: image-gallery]
HTML:

```
<div class="gallery-container container-content well" style="height: 62px;">
    <ul class="layout-gallery row">
        <li class="image col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <img src="img/layout/abstract-gandex.jpg"></img>
        </li>
        <li class="image col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <img src="img/layout/blob"></img>
        </li>
        <li class="image col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <img src="img/layout/aqua-blue-tiger.jpg"></img>
        </li>
        <li class="image col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <img src="img/layout/blue abstract2-gandex.jpg"></img>
        </li>
        <li class="image col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <img src="img/layout/blue abstract3-gandex.jpg"></img>
        </li>
        <li class="image col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <img src="img/layout/blue abstract4-gandex.jpg"></img>
        </li>
        <li class="image col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <img src="img/layout/blue abstract5-gandex.jpg"></img>
        </li>
        <li class="image col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <img src="img/layout/blue abstract6-gandex.jpg"></img>
        </li>
        <li class="image col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <img src="img/layout/blue abstract7-gandex.jpg"></img>
        </li>
        <li class="image col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <img src="img/layout/blue abstract-gandex.jpg"></img>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .gallery-container
  {
      margin-top: 2%;
      margin-bottom: 2%;
      overflow:auto;
  }
 .layout-gallery
 {         
      padding:0 0 0 0;
      margin:0 0 0 0;
      margin-top: 2%;
      margin-bottom: 2%;
  }
  .layout-gallery > li 
  {     
      list-style:none;
      margin-bottom:25px;           
  }
  .layout-gallery > li img 
  {
    display: block;
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 100%;
      border: 2px solid #E3E3E3;
      box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px #AEAEAE;
  }
```

EDIT:

The desired result to achieve the above would be like the example shown here https://500px.com/. But I have no idea how to accomplish this dynamic and responsive image behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than creating custom javascript to adjust the row and image sizes I ended up using the justified Gallery plugin. This awsome jquery plugin has allowed me to achieve the desired result + add hover over captions and lightbox/slideshow on click. Feels like cheating coz its so simple to use :)

Plugin: http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/

Answer (score 1):

Since the images are all not same height,we need to set a height or min-height for all images in common then it will be aligned in proper way..

OR

dynamically setting each row height for example like in https://500px.com/

Comment: Yes that 500px example is exactly what I need, because the images could be any size.Can you or anyone suggest the code to achieve 'dynamically setting each row height ' to get that result?

Comment: Yes you can use like in the below links http://alijafarian.com/demos/responsive-image-grids-using-css/   or if you need masonry view like https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/

Comment: yeah that masonery view is similar to the desired result (bit messy, lacking the uniform row layout) but would be a good alternative solution because it would allow to view portrait and lanscape + other sizes within the gallery!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using css

Just add this

```
.a{
   height: 300%;
  width: 200%; 
}
```

Change Height and width  as you want...

**[Check This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/cw21pxs8/)**